# Initial state is not being set using useState or useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React and I want to keep track of an array of objects (`images`) as it changes, so that I can implement undo function by restoring previous (`prevImage`) state of the array.

The problem I have is that the initial state isn't being set if do `useState(images)` or `useState([images])`. The output I get as I remove an image.

**Output**

```
Array(0) [] <- image removed, but the state is not being saved
Array(1) [ (5) […] ]
Array(2) [ (5) […], (4) […] ]
Array(3) [ (5) […], (4) […], (3) […] ]
Array(4) [ (5) […], (4) […], (3) […], (2) […] ]
```

**Desired Output**

```
Array(1) [ (5) […] ] <- 1 image removed
Array(2) [ (5) […], (4) […] ] <- 2 images removed
Array(3) [ (5) […], (4) […], (3) […] ]
Array(4) [ (5) […], (4) […], (3) […], (2) […] ]
Array(5) [ (5) […], (4) […], (3) […], (2) […], (1) […] ]
```

**Question**

How can I set the initial state to be `Array(1) [ (5) […] ]` before I remove an image?

**My Code**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';    
import data from './assets/data/images.json';

function App() {
  
  const [images, setImages] = useState(data.images)
  const [prevImage, setPrevImage] = useState([])

  
  const removeImage = (image) => {
    setPrevImage([...prevImage, [...images]])
    setImages(images.filter(i => i.id !== image.id))
    console.log(prevImage)
  }
  const restoreImage = () => {
    console.log(prevImage)
    setImages(prevImage)
  }
  const nextBatch = () => {
    localStorage.clear()
  }
  return (
    <div className={styles.App}>
      <div className={styles.buttonWrapper}>
        {
        prevImage.length > 0 ? <button onClick={() => restoreImage()}>undo</button> :
        <button onClick={() => restoreImage()} disabled>undo</button>
        }
        <button onClick={() => nextBatch()}>next batch</button>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.ImageExamples}>
      {
        images.map(image => {
          return (
            <a key={image.id} onClick={() => removeImage(image)}><img src={image.src}/></a>
          )
        })
      }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Data**

To replicate this, you will need this data.

```
{
    "images": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "src": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1696399744120-da551393c12f?w=600&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxjb2xsZWN0aW9uLXBhZ2V8Nnw0NjU0NzMxfHxlbnwwfHx8fHw%3D"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "src": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1622532824228-e1dffce3f265?w=600&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxjb2xsZWN0aW9uLXBhZ2V8M3wxNjYzMjQwfHxlbnwwfHx8fHw%3D"

        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "src": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542652735873-fb2825bac6e2?w=600&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxjb2xsZWN0aW9uLXBhZ2V8OXwxNjYzMjQwfHxlbnwwfHx8fHw%3D"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "src": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472656877636-35a4bb852385?w=600&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxjb2xsZWN0aW9uLXBhZ2V8MjB8MTU4ODI1fHxlbnwwfHx8fHw%3D"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "src": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614364655846-cd8087a5b38b?w=600&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxjb2xsZWN0aW9uLXBhZ2V8NDh8MTU4ODI1fHxlbnwwfHx8fHw%3D"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The `console.log` in `removeImage` is wrong.  `prevImage` will not have been updated yet when you log it to the console there, so the data you're seeing is always a step behind the actual state update.